# Convert fixed HTML table to relative table - keeping dimensions

Tags: html, css, pdf, html-table

I'm working on a project to create PDF files on basis of HTML and CSS. We're using the Antenna House Formatter to generate the PDF files.
The HTML files are exported out of a content management system. Unfortunately we use lots of tables in our PDF files (Technical Documentation). In the content management system we can only give fixed width to the table columns. An exported HTML table looks like this:

```
<table data-ait-rows="4" data-ait-cols="3" data-ait-width="4818" style="width:85mm;">
  <tr style="height:5.9mm;" data-ait-rowheight="333">
    <td data-ait-width="850" data-ait-bordercolors="65793" style="width:15mm;border-width:0pt;border-color:#010101;">
      <p class="basestyle" data-ait-style_id="8092" data-ait-stylename="Base style" data-ait-rs="0" data-ait-list="4" data-ait-level="1" data-ait-format="">Signalwort</p>
    </td>
    <td data-ait-width="1984" data-ait-bordercolors="65793" style="width:35mm;border-width:0pt;border-color:#010101;">
      <p class="basestyle" data-ait-style_id="8092" data-ait-stylename="Base style" data-ait-rs="0" data-ait-list="4" data-ait-level="1" data-ait-format="">Eintrittswahrscheinlichkeit</p>
    </td>
    <td data-ait-width="1984" data-ait-bordercolors="65793" style="width:35mm;border-width:0pt;border-color:#010101;">
      <p class="basestyle" data-ait-style_id="8092" data-ait-stylename="Base style" data-ait-rs="0" data-ait-list="4" data-ait-level="1" data-ait-format="">Schwere der Gefahr bei Missachtung</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Is it possible to convert the fixed width of the table (85mm) and the fixed column widths (15mm/35mm/35mm) into percentage values with keeping the dimensions? 
Technical writers set the table width per drag and drop in the content management system. Those values are taken in the HTML file. The aim is to transform their set proportions automatically in percentage.

I thought I read a little time ago about such a way but after some hours of searching I couldn't find anything...If someone has an idea please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different approaches it seems to be pretty easy. For my use case following solution works just fine:

```
table {table-layout: auto !important;}
td {width: auto ! important;}
tr {width: auto ! important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the widths, it’s easy. Their relative sizes are 15 and 35 parts to 85 (15 and 35 mm to your table width of 85 mm). In other words, you can set these to be `width: calc (15% / 85%);` and `width: calc(35% / 85%);`. As for the width of the table itself, it wasn’t clear whether you wanted that to be relative as well, or full width. If it is supposed to have the same relative size, then you need to know the relation to the units. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) lists the relevant ones as such:

- mm   millimeters [undefined]
- in   inches (1in = 96px = 2.54cm)

This means that 25.4 mm = 1″ = 96 px; therefore, 85 mm = (85 ÷ 25.4 × 96) px ≈ 321 px.

With heights, though, I’m a bit unsure; in my experience I’ve had some wonky results. They are, though, both of them, supposed to be relative to screen size, so width and height 100% is supposed to fill the entire screen – no more, no less.

I hope this helps.